# SimpleXML Dynamic element names

Tags: php, simplexml

```
echo $xml->SLOT1->Effect;
echo $xml->SLOT2->Effect;
echo $xml->SLOT3->Effect;
```

Is there a way to simplify this by using a `for` loop? I tried this but it echos nothing:

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 3; $x++) {
   echo $xml->SLOT[$x]->Effect;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
$xml->{"SLOT".$x}->Effect;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 3; $x++) {
   echo $xml->{SLOT.$x}->Effect;
}
```